# «Будут спрашивать, – говорю Васину, – отдувайся за двоих!» - сложноподчиненное предложение в прямой речи?

Tags: прямая-речь, спп

Из [заданий](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/uprr1_18) сайта "Лицей"

> «Будут спрашивать, – говорю Васину, – отдувайся за двоих!»

Я задумался: можно ли рассматривать "Будут спрашивать - отдувайся за двоих!" как сложноподчиненное (с придаточным обстоятельственным условия):

> **Если** будут спрашивать, **то** отдувайся за двоих!

Или же это два отдельных предложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я задумался: можно ли рассматривать "Будут спрашивать - отдувайся за
>   двоих!" как сложноподчиненное...

Союзов и союзных слов нет. Значит, **бессоюзное сложное предложение**.